# What's the better approach to write Magento modules?

Tags: magento

my question is dedicated to programmers who **already written at least one Magento module**.
I am writing a Magento module that will heavily interact with other Magento modules.
So, my question is: in the Adminhtml, do you rather use Magento widgets (grid, tabs, accordion...) or do you write your own blocks?
Would be awsome if some people share their experience here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really probably depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are able to make your module work well with the widgets, then I say go for it. It will give your module a consistent look and feel with the rest of Magento so [hopefully] most of the users of your module will feel right at home.

Personally, I have had a difficult time making all of them work because of the lack of documentation on them (If you think finding how to do stuff on the front end is difficult, wait till you try looking for backend stuff).

However, if you find that your module will have a hard time working inside the confines of the widgets, then I do not see any hard in making your own blocks.

Really in the end it comes down to what your module requires.

Comment: Actually, I perfectly master magento widgets, my module (almoust finished) overrides all magento widgets (new look, and all ajax) I was wondering if I should handle custom written adminhtml blocks (if a user install a new module). I wanted to know how often module programmers write their own blocks VS using magento widgets

Comment: In my experience most modules use the default widgets